# Deferred objects in jquery

Tags: jquery, deferred

I make three ajax requests in jquery, the first two I want to make simultanious, and the third ajax request, I wanna make only after the two are completed.
How can I achieve this with using a deferred object in jquery?

Comment: `$.when(promis1, promise2).then(function () {});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.when(ajax1)
.done(ajax2)
.done(ajax3);
```

and you can use it like this too

```
$.when(ajax1, ajax2)
.done(ajax3);
```

Comment: I don't know if this is good, in developer tools, ajax2 is made, then ajax3, then ajax1 is made, but gets inserted before the first two ajaxcalls

Comment: Your second option is what the OP asked for, not the first.  You could fill in a little more detail to show how you're passing the returned promise from the ajax calls to `$.when()` to make this answer more complete.